# How to get the OBJECT name of a Worksheet?

Tags: object, worksheet

I need to work with the OBJECT names of the Worksheets in my Workbook, because even if the user changes the Worksheet name, I still could find it using the OBJECT name.

In the image below, all Worksheets have their "given name" and their Object name. See the highlighted one: It's given name is "Doppler Brachial", and it's Object name is "Planilha13" ("Worksheet13" in Portuguese). Even if the user changes the "Doppler Brachial" to "DpBr Analitical" (for example), I could still locate the necessary data by referring to "Planilha13".

Any aideas? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was so anxious that I missed a step...

Instead of using **Sheet(n).Name** (wich will give-me the index name "Doppler Brachial" of the worksheet), i should use **Sheet(n).CodeName**.

That picks the "Planilha13" name, the one that does not change, regardless of the Worksheet name or its position.

Thanks anyway! Best regards!